# .htaccess for redirecting to localhost project root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost

I have my PHP localhost project in folder named myproject in XAMPP localhost directory. Inside this project I need to use some hyperlinks, for example:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

if I am on:

> http://localhost/myproject/something

On production server this get me to the root of project (home), but on localhost I get:

> http://localhost/xampp/

instead of

> http://localhost/myproject

How can I do this? I guess it will be something with .htaccess file. Thank you for advice

Comment: [get started with .htaccess](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/guide-to-htaccess/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in your `httpd.conf` `xampp` and replace by `myproject` and restart your web server :

```
DocumentRoot "C:/.../xampp/.."
```

and `<Directory "C:/..../xampp/../"> ...`

Comment: The OP needs to use the .htaccess file, not make changes to the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Changing httpd.conf file is one way to figure it out, but much better solution is redirecting by using .htaccess. If I need to run another project, changes in httpd.conf can become problematic.