# How to change the root of a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, document-root

On my xampp server, I have several folders in `/projects/` with different projects. The problem is when I make the link to the home page, I can't simply put in `/` because instead of going to `localhost/projects/currentproj/`, it goes to `localhost`.

Normally, I would just set all the href links to `/localhost/projects/currentproj/`, but I upload this project to a website so the website would have an incorrect link. I have temporarily set the links as local ones, with `./` instead of `/`, but I would like a more permanent solution if possible, and I don't know how to format htaccess files.

In other words, I would like to know how to change the root of a subdirectory, so all files in that folder go to the root of their own folder when linked to the root, rather than leaving that subdirectory.

EDIT:

[Here](https://gyazo.com/b2b5a82741e4a7fd92e1e953772cec2e) is a perfect example of why this would be helpful.
That is what my 404 page looks like when I go to `localhost/projects/currentproj/sub/example`. If I could use `/` for the root of the `currentproj` folder, this wouldnt be an issue.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026975/htaccess-for-redirecting-to-localhost-project-root?rq=1) is an example of someone else with the same issue, but they never got a proper answer. There has to be a way to change this in the htaccess file.

Comment: What's wrong with using `./`? Isn't that a common and perfectly valid approach?

Comment: @ObsidianAge My only concern is I have page files in deeper folders, and it would be easier to link `/` rather than `../../` etc.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I added a valid example of why this would be very helpful.